# Prove that the recurrence relation $b_k = -4 \frac{n}{k} \left( b_{k-1} + b_{k-2} \right)$ is never zero.

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics

Let the following recurrence relation be given:

$b_0 = 1$

$b_1 = -4$

$b_k = -4 \frac{n}{k} \left( b_{k-1} + b_{k-2} \right)$ with $ k \leq n$ and $k,n \in \mathbb{N}$

$n$ is a constant.

**Question: How can I prove that $b_k \neq 0$ ?**

So far, I am able to prove that $b_k \neq 0$ if $b_k$ would be defined without the fraction as:

$b_k = -4 \left( b_{k-1} + b_{k-2} \right)$

But from there on I am unable to describe the effect of the fraction $\frac{n}{k} \geq 1$.

Comment: What is $n$?  Is it a constant?  If so, what does it mean to say that $k≤n$?  Is it a variable?

Comment: Yes $n$ is a constant. I am looking for $b_k \neq 0$ from $k = 1$ up to $k = n$.

Comment: I suggest editing your post to clarify that. "asymptotics" tends to refer to limiting functional behavior for large arguments, but here you only have finitely many terms to consider.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have edited my post.

Comment: It seems as if it should be easy to get a good lower bound on $|b_k|$.  In practice the absolute sequence grows very quickly.  But so far I don't have anything that gets the job done.

Comment: I agree with lulu, I done some experiments https://justpaste.it/214bd , excepts for n<6
the minimum $b_k$ from $k\ge 2$ seems always to be $b_2=3n$ and yes, the average term grow very fast in absolute value. Yet for $n=11$ you can see that it is $b_{10}$ that realizes the second minimum, even if for larger values of $n$ it seems that $b_3$ and subsequent terms are always much larger than $b_2$. So I guess it is not so easy to prove.

Comment: Thank you for trying. I thought that this would be some kind of "easy", too. I have broken my example down as far as I could. Because it seems to be a general thing. If I determine that $b_k \neq 0$ for the recurrence relation without the fraction, I see numerically that it is true for the definition of $b_k$ with the fraction.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed we have $|b_k|≥2|b_{k-1}|$ in the range.

This is clear for small $k$, and we proceed by induction.  Suppose that we have shown that $|b_{k-1}|≥2|b_{k-2}|$.

Then we have $$|b_k|≥4|b_{k-1}+b_{k-2}|$$

(note:  this is where we use $n≥k$)

Now, since $|b_{k-2}|≤\frac 12|b_{k-1}|$ we see that $$|b_{k-1}+b_{k-2}|≥|b_{k-1}|-|b_{k-2}|≥\frac 12|b_{k-1}|$$ and we are done.

Comment: nice, we can simplifiy the induction with $|b_k|>2^k$ now. Since $\frac nk\ge 1$ and $4\times|2^{k-1}-2^{k-2}|=4\times 2^{k-2}=2^k$ the induction is verified.

Comment: @zwim  Yes, good point.